# Web service PHP + Android application

Tags: php, android, json, apache, wampserver

Using eclipse i create a simple abdroid application which communicate with MYSQL data base using PHP scripts, i start writing my PHP Web Service and i put those files under 'www' of my Wamp server.
in fact Wamp server is using two servers

1. 1.web server ( Apache)
2. 2.Mysql

after doing those steps i run my android application under eclipse ide and i get all things works..
I m trying to understand the process behind all that.
My Android application by runnig send an HTTP request to the PHP web service, then ,the apache Web server in Wamp Server executes the php script and do some oparation on the data base ,after that the result is reterning to the Android application ( the result in Json format), and finaly the application decode the Json object and display the result

is it right? please correcte me if i m wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct if you want it to be a simple request-driven web service (such as HTTP in your case).